# How can I get the count of sample from AudioButterList

Tags: audiounit

I get the AudioBufferList from a wav file. (The sample frequency is 44100Hz and the time length is 2 second). However, I can't get a 44100*2=88200 sample. I get a AudioBufferList which contains 512 NumberBuffers. How can I get the sample from the AudioBufferList?

Comment: Maybe you mean `AuditoBufferList`?

Comment: And watch your spelling otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

u get the number of frames in file using:

```
AudioUnitGetProperty(<#AudioUnit inUnit#>, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount, <#AudioUnitScope inScope#>, <#AudioUnitElement inElement#>, <#void *outData#>, <#UInt32 *ioDataSize#>)
```